# Looking for a faster solution to 'maximum number of teams' problem

Tags: python, list, performance

My solution exceeds the time limit and I can't come up with a faster solution, still very much a beginner. How can I improve it?

The problem:

A perfect ICPC team is made up of at least 1 mathematician and 1 programmer and it must have 3 members. You have the number of mathematicians, programmers and students that have no specialization. What is the maximum number of perfect teams you can make? C students are programmers, M students are mathematicians and X don't have a specialization.

Example input:

```
1 1 1
```

Example output:

```
1
```

Example input:

```
3 6 0
```

Example output:

```
3
```

Example input:

```
10 1 10
```

Example output:

```
1
```

My solution:

```
    cmx = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    i = 0
    
    while 0 not in cmx:
        cmx[0] -= 1
        cmx[1] -= 1
        cmx[2] -= 1
        i += 1
    
    if cmx[0] != 0 and cmx[1] != 0 and cmx[2] == 0:
        while sum(cmx) >= 3 and cmx[0] != 0 and cmx[1] != 0:
            if cmx[0] >= cmx[1]:
                cmx[0] -= 2
                cmx[1] -= 1
                i += 1
            elif cmx[0] < cmx[1]:
                cmx[0] -= 1
                cmx[1] -= 2
                i += 1
    
    print(i)
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it isn't min(M, C, (M + C + X) // 3).

Comment: @FrankYellin, I thought about `(c + m + x - min(c, m)) // 2` or `>> 1` *(shift should be faster)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght It doesnt work for the `10 1 10` testcase.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish, I know, that's why you don't see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that M ≤ C.  (Proof works identically if C ≤ M).  How many teams can I make.  It's clear that if  M + C + X ≥ 3M, then I can easily make M teams.  (Every team has a mathematician, a programmer, and either a second programmer or a "none".) And I can't make more than M teams.  If M + C + X < 3M, then the most I can have is (M + C + X) / 3 teams, and again you make them the same way, since you have sufficient mathematicians and programmers.

The proof works identically if C ≤ M.

So min(M, C, (M + C + X) // 3).   As stated above.

---

A simpler way of looking at it is that C, M, and (C + M + X)//3 are each, independently, an upper bound on the number of teams that you can form.  You just have to show the smallest of these three upper bounds is, in fact, a reachable value.

Comment: You can edit and provide this code: `cmx = [int(x) for x in input().split()]`
`print(min(sum(cmx)//3 , cmx[0], cmx[1]))`

Comment: I presume that the OP doesn't need to have his hand held.  He already knew how to read the input and handle the output.  I was just showing what to do in the middle.

Comment: Feeling very stupid right now because I can't wrap my head around how you came to the "if M + C + X ≥ 3M, then I can easily make M teams." and "If M + C + X < 3M, then the most I can have is (M + C + X) / 3 teams" conclusions..

Comment: If M + C + X ≥ 3M, (and we know M ≤ C), then C + X ≥ 2M.  I can easily make M teams consisting of an mathematician (there are M of them), a programmer (there are more than M of them), and someone (once I remove M programmers, I still have more than M people remaining.).  In the other direction, every team has at least three people, so I can't have more than (M + C + X) // 3 teams, no matter what the rules are.